# Select all subscriptions whose users don't have any other active subscription

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a subscription cleanup query that should select all canceled subscriptions, whose users don't have any other active subscription (the application allows multiple subscriptions per user).

I started with this:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions s WHERE status = 'canceled' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptions s2 where s2.user_id = s.user_id AND status = 'active') = 0;
```

However, I feel there must be an easier/more straightforward/more performant way.

Comment: *"However, I feel there must be an easier/more straightforward/more performant way."* Yes this co related subquery is most likely better written as a join instead ..

Comment: But see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results. As this is a performance question the question should also include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question so we know the indexes and columns types.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  inner join will not work here... you're looking for rows with no matching record - you need an outer join for that

Comment: aha - see you changed inner join to join - plain join is equivalent to inner join - so outer should still be specified.

Comment: i said "a join" @FizzBuzz but never mind Grammer where are going offtopic here, we can best remove these comments where we are discussing this.

Comment: not sure where grammar comes into play here - 
join and outer join will give you completely different results. this has nothing to do with grammar in any which way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT EXISTS can be more intuitive here:

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions s WHERE status = 'canceled' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM subscriptions s2 where s2.user_id = s.user_id AND status = 'active');
```

You can also use a LEFT JOIN here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
subscriptions s LEFT OUTER JOIN
subscriptions s2 ON s.USER_ID = s2.USER_ID AND s2.status='active'
WHERE status = 'canceled' AND s2.id IS NULL
```